# How do I change ReceivedTime of emails in Outlook VBA? It says it is write-protected

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am new to VBA and also new here.

Background:
I have just migrated some users from an IMAP server to Exchange. Everything went well except for one user that uses Apple mail app in MacOS. I moved within that app but the sent messages got messed up. The mail app sets the current time as the received time. The mail app and the maiapp in iPhone also uses this timestamp for sorting. So, now I have to find a way to change the received time to the sent time.

I found an answer here:
https://vox.veritas.com/t5/Enterprise-Vault/EV-is-it-possible-to-change-the-date-when-an-email-was-journaled/td-p/590495

I modified it slightly. The error I get is that Item.ReceivedTime is write-protected. How do I get around this?

```
Sub sent-received()
    Set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
    Set Msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    For Each Item In Msg.Items
        Item.ReceivedTime = Item.SentOn
        Item.Save
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have redemption?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info! I just read about it and it sounds like that’s what I need. Will try that and get back if it worked.

Comment: Thank you! That was what was wrong in the first place. The only thing except for installing Redemtion that did not work with the original script from goatboy at Veritas page, was that it was not possible to name the object Session. When I renamed it to rSesstion it worked. This is the script I finally used:

Comment: How do I add code in a comment? I looks messed up. Should I paste it in my original question or how? I guess that I do not know the rules here :)

Comment: Edit to ur question,

Comment: Let’s check with @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: Replace the line `Set Msg = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` with `Set Msg = rSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder)`.